# Rainfall interpolation using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, extract, precipitation

I have a layer that describe rainfall for 10 years. Now I want to interpolate the area in ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) 10.7. As you know I should define some point on my area to extract the rainfall from the Layer.

How should I define these points i.e. in the center of pixels or more?

This is my Layer and a closed Border:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to interpolate? You already have rainfall surfaces.

Comment: Thanks, I want to smooth the colors. as you there are many squares in the Layer (bcoz the resolution is 0.25"x0.25").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Resample](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/resample.htm) tool and specify bilinear or cubic as the resampling type.

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is just to smooth the colors, then no need to resample the data. You should only use resample during display feature in Display tab within Layer Properties window, and choose Bilinear Interpolation, instead of Nearest Neighbor as the default.

Nearest Neighbor (default)
[image: Nearest Neighbor (default)]

Bilinear Interpolation
[image: Bilinear Interpolation]

Comment: Thanks you, it's very useful, the result is excellent :)

Comment: Dear, also I have another problem. there is "no data" near some pixel at the cost. https://imgur.com/nsxHnZt ,How should I interpolate the area?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Resample tool with Bilinear method to resample only the Layer :

[image]

then I went to Symbology Tab and set the Show to Classify:
[image]

now you see the result:

[image]